# Possible Security/Privacy Threats with 'Content Disposition'

Tags: http-headers, content-disposition

I remember some blog saying that response header `Content-Disposition` may cause security threats and the user's privacy is vulnerable. I also remember it stating that the header is not part of the `HTTP Specs` but I just can not find the blog or any proper article that why it is said so?

Please provide a simple code example to demo the same.

Answer (score 0):

Content-Disposition is an HTTP header field; consult the IANA header field registry for the RFC definining it (and, hint: that RFC contains a section called "Security Considerations").

Comment: Please update your answer with the relevant link and for some people like me it is better and fast to understand if you could provide some sample/minimalistic/demo javaScript code.

Comment: a)  do a web search for "IANA header field registry" and you'll find <http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml>, b) I do not see what this has to do with JS.

Comment: a) I have seen that link before, but that just does not give me an idea of how the parameter "filename or filename*" can breach into an user's privacy? b) Secondly I am sorry if I sought the solution only related to JS as I thought there might be some JS code they might be injecting as part of file-content which may steal any private/secure information of user. Anyways I am open for any sample solution beyond JS also.